# Can I downgrade ASP.NET Core project from version 5.0 to 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I finished my ASP.NET Core MVC project on .NET Core 5.0. Can I downgrade this project from version 5.0 to 3.1? Could someone explain? Because I need it in that version.

Comment: ***WHY*** do you need it in that version - that's going to be out of support by December 2022 ?

Comment: Was going to say the same...